# Auto-Complete Hints for Javascript and Jquery in Coda 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, coda

Does anybody know of a way to get auto-complete for javascript in Code 2?

Coda to is really helpful and is really good with this especially in CSS and html. 
But when it comes to javascript or using jquery it doesn't seem to show me the methods or functions. 
It is really helpful in CSS where it shows you all the different options. I there is no possible way to do this in Coda 2 are there any applications that you would recommend that are really good at this?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you have found it already, but in case others stumble onto this, take a look here:
https://github.com/rayman813/coda2-mode-jquery